# On the existence and uniqueness of solution for a regime-switching Black-Scholes problem (coupled parabolic problems)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces, finance, parabolic-pde

I am currently working on a regime-switching Black-Scholes model and am having trouble determining the existence and uniqueness of a solution for the problem. Specifically, I am interested in finding the solution to the regime-switching Black-Scholes equation with two regimes:

State 1:
$$
\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma_1^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 V_1}{\partial S^2}+(r-\delta) S \frac{\partial V_1}{\partial S}-r V_1=\lambda_{12}\left(V_1-V_2\right)
$$
with boundary conditions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_1(0, t) & =0 \\
\lim _{S \rightarrow \infty} V_1(S, t) & =S \\
V_1(S, T) & =\max \{S-E, 0\} .
\end{aligned}
$$
State 2:
$$
\frac{\partial V_2}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma_2^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 V_2}{\partial S^2}+(r-\delta) S \frac{\partial V_2}{\partial S}-r V_2=\lambda_{21}\left(V_2-V_1\right)
$$
with boundary conditions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_2(0, t) & =0 \\
\lim _{S \rightarrow \infty} V_2(S, t) & =S \\
V_2(S, T) & =\max \{S-E, 0\} .
\end{aligned}
$$

I am wondering what techniques can be used to determine the existence and uniqueness of a solution for this problem, and what conditions need to be satisfied for a solution to exist and be unique.

None of the references ([(1)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/974/1/012024/pdf),[(2)](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0898122112005378?token=11B0336C075A348A186E1BAF46F43859A924AA58538D52DAD7F23498368496A3109C604BE6794420AF5C686F7162DA4A&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230214090551),[(3)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/5A15C82EE2006D03A339EB693BDC90E3/S1446181117000335a.pdf/pricing-european-options-on-regime-switching-assets-a-comparative-study-of-monte-carlo-and-finite-difference-approaches.pdf)) provide us any thing about the existence and uniqueness of solutions for two-state regime switching option pricing models, while the generalized Black-Scholes models (described in page no : [1485](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0895717711006455?token=4B8B2C0A00581FF1FF03097580C67B04755E6B037149639A256E3B92D27AD7FA059047E424CC3FC9939A1449F801D7B4&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230214094709), [779](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0898122115000851?token=2546FF3F63A9D97DBD80E82F655B663D6AC0AF513E119386B1A198746000CABBEDAA229B12672AF47466F82996DEC010&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230214094922), [1768](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S187705091630922X?token=AB9B5E50BF65CA7D7B7576283EE2F17DE5BD2A944096DB4A8EFFCB11DBE8B6D88F4C5476FD7DA69530C5560DF154CA86&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230214094926),[2229](https://www.aimspress.com/fileOther/PDF/Math/math-05-03-147.pdf)) possess existence and uniqueness of solutions under reasonable regularity conditions.

I felt uncomfortable with the necessity and sensibility of numerical solutions for option pricing models (Equations [(12) and (13)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/974/1/012024/pdf)) under regime switching economy. Can we say the anything about the existence and uniqueness of such models?

Thank you for your help!